# Calling a REST service through Azure Service Bus: 405 method not allowed

Tags: rest, azure, servicebus

I am trying to create a Windows Phone connecting to a REST service, by using a Windows Azure Service Bus.

I developed my rest service (it's a Windows Service), and now I use fiddler to test it.

But I keep getting the error "405 method not allowed".

Things I noticed:

- My service is online, because when I shut it down, fiddler returns me another error.
- My Servicebus is up and running, as I can see it on the Azure portal.

This is the operation I am trying to call in C#

```
[WebInvoke(
//UriTemplate = "GetEmployees?Action=Get", // URI:"https://<MyBus>.servicebus.windows.net/GetEmployeesRest/GetEmployees?Action=Create"
UriTemplate = "GetEmployees?Action=Create", 
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]

public DEVEmployee[] GetEmployees()
{

}
```

My url configured in the app.config is:

```
<baseAddresses>
<add baseAddress="https://<MyBus>.servicebus.windows.net/GetEmployeesRest/"/>
</baseAddresses>
```

The way I call it then is:

https://.servicebus.windows.net/GetEmployeesRest/GetEmployees?Action=Create

With an Authorization header.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Service Bus Relay?

Comment: Yes I am using service bus relay. I can see the bus to my service in the azure portal. But it always returns me a 405.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default WebInvoke uses POST requests (WebGet uses GET requests). If your client invokes the GetEmployees method in your example using anything other than a POST request the service will respond with a 405.

It is possible to override the default HTTP Method like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="PUT", UriTemplate = "?Action:Create",
  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
void CreateEmployee(string id, string name);
```

If you are testing using Fiddler, then the Composer lets you select the method to use when you submit a request.

If you want to test from Fiddler without the need to include an authorization header, you can use this configuration for your service:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpRelayBinding>
    <binding name="default">
      <security relayClientAuthenticationType="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpRelayBinding>
</bindings>
```